# "Kernel panic" in loading and devtmpfs mounting error into craneboard(am3517_crane)

Tags: kernel, mount, omap

I've compiled inserted MLO and uboot.img file into MMC card and now trying to load "**rootfs**".there is problem in loading.Following are lines at the end of LOG..:

> kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
>
> EXT3-fs (mmcblk0p2): using internal journal
>
> EXT3-fs (mmcblk0p2): recovery complete
>
> EXT3-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode
>
> VFS: Mounted root (ext3 filesystem) on device 179:2.
>
> devtmpfs: error mounting -2
>
> Freeing init memory: 164K
>
> Kernel panic - not syncing: No init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. See Linux Documentation/init.txt for guidance.

output of printenv is:

> AM3517_CRANE # printenv
>
> baudrate=115200
>
> bootargs=console=ttyO2,115200n8 omapfb.vram=0:4M,1:4M omapfb.mode=dvi:1280x800MR-32@60 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootfstype=ext3 rootwait fixrtc nohlt
>
> bootcmd=mmc dev ${mmcdev}; if mmc rescan; then echo mmc detected; if run loadbootscript; then echo Load bootscript; run bootscript; saveenv; fi; echo SD/MMC found on device ${mmcdev}; if run loaduimage; then run mmcboot; else run nandboot; fi; else run nandboot; fi
>
> bootdelay=5
>
> bootfile=uImage
>
> bootscript=echo Running bootscript from mmc ...; source ${loadaddr}
>
> console=ttyO2,115200n8
>
> dieid#=4294000100000000015da3960401c020
>
> ethact=DaVinci-EMAC
>
> ethaddr=00:E0:4C:53:44:58
>
> filesize=394
>
> ipaddr=123.12.0.3
>
> loadaddr=0x82000000
>
> loadbootscript=fatload mmc ${mmcdev} ${loadaddr} boot.scr
>
> loaduimage=fatload mmc ${mmcdev} ${loadaddr} uImage
>
> mmcargs=setenv bootargs console=ttyO2 omapfb.vram=0:4M,1:4M omapfb.mode=dvi:1280x800MR-32@60
>
> root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootfstype=ext3 rootwait fixrtc nohlt
>
> mmcboot=echo Booting from mmc ...; run mmcargs; bootm ${loadaddr}
>
> mmcdev=0
>
> nandargs=setenv bootargs console=${console} root=/dev/mtdblock4 rw rootfstype=jffs2
>
> nandboot=echo Booting from nand ...; run nandargs; nand read ${loadaddr} 280000 400000; bootm ${loadaddr}
>
> serverip=123.12.0.2
>
> stderr=serial
>
> stdin=serial
>
> stdout=serial
>
> Environment size: 1249/131068 bytes

Is problem related to rootfs or uboot or environment variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this error come due to not having rootfs in ext3 partition.Check your root(EXT3) partition of sd-card whether rootfs is available or not?

Comment: Yes.problem solved..file system was missing in root folder of SD card.

Answer (score 2):

In particular, AFAIK the line `devtmpfs: error mounting -2` indicates that there isn't devtmpfs mounting point present in the root partition. That means it is sufficient to run the command `cd <future_rootfs_mounting_point> && sudo mkdir dev` to cease this error message.

(I assume there are CONFIG_DEVTMPFS and CONFIG_DEVTMPFS_MOUNT kernel options enabled.)

I decided to write about this as it may happen that you even have a partition marked as rootfs, but it doesn't have proper internal configuration.